# Get a FieldDescriptor without hard-coding the field name (proto message)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Given the following proto message

```proto
message MyMsg {
  string my_field = 1;
  string your_field=2;
}
```

...the [protoreflect](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#section-documentation) package can be used to get a descriptor for each field

```golang
protoMessage := myMsg.ProtoReflect()
messageDescriptor := protoMessage.Descriptor() // protobuf type information
fieldDescriptors := messageDescriptor.Fields() // list of field declarations
```

Getting a [field descriptor](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#FieldDescriptor) for a specific field is trivial

```golang
fieldDescriptor := fieldDescriptors.ByTextName("my_field") // describes a field
```

Can this be achieved without hard-coding the field name `"my_field"`? I guess it would be nice to use the generated code to refer to the field I'm interested in. Something like (not working code)

```golang
fieldDescriptor := fieldDescriptors.ByTextName(pb.MyMsg.MyField) // describes a field
```

This way, if the field name changes, it will be caught at compile time, or even from static analysis by an IDE.

The [FieldDescriptors](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#FieldDescriptors) type has three methods for getting a field descriptor by name:

- `ByName(s Name)`
- `ByJSONName(s string)`
- `ByTextName(s string)`

`ByJSONName` and `ByTextName` both require hard-coded field names (as strings), and by `ByName` accepts a [Name](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#Name) which is type'd to a string. The upshot is, I don't see anything in the [protoreflect](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#section-documentation) package that points to a solution.

**Context**

[Field masks](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/field-mask) are the [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods#update) way to support partial resource updates.  It's trivial to iterate over the masks provided in a field mask

```golang
protoMessage := myMsg.ProtoReflect()
messageDescriptor := protoMessage.Descriptor() // protobuf type information
fieldDescriptors := messageDescriptor.Fields() // list of field declarations

// iterate over the field paths in the field mask
for _, p := range mask.GetPaths() {

    // find the field descriptor for the field path
    fieldDescriptor := fieldDescriptors.ByTextName(p)

    if fieldDescriptor == nil {
        // field descriptor cannot be found for the field path
        return
    }

    // great, the field path points to a field, let's use it

    switch p {
    case "my_field":
        // the client wants to update MyMsg.my_field

    case "your_field":
        // the client wants to update  MyMsg.your_field
    }
}
```

The problem is, in order to actually update the correct field in `MyMsg`, it's necessary to hard-code the field name in the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The [interface](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#FieldDescriptors) has `ByNumber` too

I assume (I've not used the method) that you could give this `1` from your example.

And `Get`, of course so that you can enumerate all of the FieldDescriptors.

I think it's not unreasonable to want to reflect (!) the generated (struct) types and enumerate across them but it feels like turtles-all-the-way-down.

It may help solicit other answers if you could present the problem that you're unable to solve without the desired method?

Comment: Added more context.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarity and your reasoning. I'm unfamiliar with PATCH'ing resources and so I recommend you wait for folks more familiar with this to comment but, it seems to me that somewhere in your code, you need to define a 1:1 mapping between field names and some field-specific functionality. If you use `switch` then you'd have to hardcode the enumerated values but could you not replace the `switch` with a function that takes the field name string or field id and matches it to the desired functionality.

Comment: I think the function you describe is the function that (in my implementation) contains the `switch` statement.